# Laptop does not turn on unless plugged in; battery works after powering on

Tags: laptop, power-supply

I have a Dell Latitude D630 Laptop, which will only power up when the power adapter is plugged in. It will not power up on battery only. Once powered up I can unplug the adapter and it will run on the battery. The adapter works properly in charging the battery as well. The battery holds a charge for the duration I'm using it.

How can I get the laptop to turn on without the adapter plugged in when starting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Make sure BIOS is the latest version.
- Make sure there is no issue with the connector pins on the battery, such as bent or corroded pins, or other physical issues with the battery.
- Make sure there is no corrosion on the battery pins where they connect to the motherboard.  If you find corrosion, replace the motherboard.
- Try draining battery completely, leave it out of the system for a day, then charge it fully.
- You may need to replace the battery anyway, even though it works fine when the system is started from AC power.  This laptop is rather old and if you still have the original battery that came with it, it may be starting to go out.
- If this happens even with a different, known working battery, the motherboard might need to be replaced.

Comment: I will check them. Couple quick questions and notes before doing the above. Why would it be #2 and #3 if it runs well on the battery after I disconnect the power cord? Seems to me the connectors are good as long as it is running on battery only.

Comment: It could be that the power up sequence requires a larger draw on the battery (like a car, for instance) and that either the pins are not making contact to start the machine or an issue like that is preventing the battery from sending enough power to start the device.

Comment: BIOS was good. Did not see any corrosion. Everything looked clean. I obtained this laptop from someone else who said the battery is pretty new. I have a D630 of my own. I used the battery from that one and the problem was still there. So that tells me the battery is not the problem. If it is a motherboard problem, why can't I just continue using it by booting it up with the power adapter?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with my Acer laptop. I used the battery reset button under my laptop, left it without power for 5 min and then recharged. I have not had any problems since. I don't know if this button is a common feature for other brands.